# How can I prove a simple method of a controller on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, methods, controller

I would like to try the custom_pow method of ApplicationController controller in order to verify what works correctly, but whenever I execute rspec, the following message appears:

wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)

In ApplicationController:

```
def custom_pow
    params[:x] * params[:x]
end
```

In ApplicationController (_spec):

```
Rspec.describe ApplicationController, type: :controller do
    test "should get custom_pow" do
        get custom_pow, params: {x:1}
        assert_response :success
    end
 end
```

I would like to corroborate that custom_pow works correctly. I would specially like to indicate an expectative, for example, of 64 and to try the method with a value of 8.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess it is referred to the method `test`, which requires two arguments: `test "should get custom_pow", "other"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to send symbol instead of String or object. Like this 
`get :custom_pow, params...`